# How to Dial a call from multi caller number at same time to multi number in twilio in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, twilio

I have 5 Twilio number for calling my customer, I have huge number to dial. so that I want to assign 2 agent to dial & contact my client. now I want to start Dial from those 5 number at same time when i click a button and dial list is one (MySql Database) using PHP. when one client number disconnect try next client number. can't understand how to start that code. I use following code for dialing

```
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls
           ->create("+14155551212", // to
                    "+15017122661", // from
                    [
                        "twiml" => "<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>"
                    ]
           );
?>
```

How I dial from 5 number at the same time?

Comment: Every phone call is an HTTP POST request to the API to create a call. In order to call from 5 phone numbers you'll have to make 5 POST requests to the API. In the case of your code you'd create a loop that fires off the `$twilio->calls->create()` each time it passes through the loop. That aside, I'd like to better understand your use case. Are you saying you want to have 5 phone calls initiated and when the first two are answered then connect those 2 calls to agents and cancel the other 3?

Comment: yes, when 2 calls connect to agent in that time cancel / pause rest 3, and after complete connected call again dial start.....